# Basis for set of linear operators of $\text{span}_{\mathbb{R}}\{1,\omega\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Consider the vector space $V:=\text{span}_{\mathbb{R}}\{1,\omega\}$, where $\omega$ is the third complex root of unity. The set

$$W=\{f:V\rightarrow V\mid f \text{ is linear}\}$$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ of dimension 2, right?

I am just trying to find another basis. I try this: If I take $f_1$ to be identity operator and $f_2$ maps

$$1\mapsto \frac{1+2\omega}{\sqrt{3}}$$
$$\omega \mapsto \frac{-2-\omega}{\sqrt{3}}$$

I see that $W=\text{span}_{\mathbb{R}}\{f_1,f_2\}$, is it correct?

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

$V$ is two-dimensional (it's actually $\Bbb C\cong \Bbb R^2$). Which means that the vector space of linear maps $V\to V$ corresponds to the vector space of $2\times2$ matrices, which is $4$-dimensional.

Comment: Oh. Thanks. I actually know that. However, I wonder where my mistake is? I could not find one $f\in W$ not in the span of $f_1$ and $f_2$?

Comment: @21understanding Writing them in matrix form might ease your search: $$f_1=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}\\f_2=\frac1{\sqrt3}\begin{bmatrix}1&-2\\2&-1\end{bmatrix}$$To find a full linearly independent set we can note that any element in the span of $f_1,f_2$ with a zero in the top left entry has the remaining three entries equal in absolute value. So, for instance, $f_3,f_4$ given by $$f_3(1)=\omega,f_3(\omega)=0\\f_4(1)=0,f_4(\omega)=1$$will expand $\{f_1,f_2\}$ to a basis.